# adding httpSecurity.csrf().disable() to spring security configuration is allowing unauthenticated endpoint calls

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have the following security configuration for my springboot project

```
@Override
   public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
       web.ignoring().antMatchers("/test_url_1");
   }

   @Override
   public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

       httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
               .authorizeRequests()
               .anyRequest().authenticated()
               .and()
               .logout()
               .invalidateHttpSession(true)
               .clearAuthentication(true)
               .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
       httpSecurity.addFilterBefore(jwtRequestFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
   }
```

now I have another endpoint /test_url_2. Calling which should be redirected to error page for an unauthorized user. If am removing `csrf().disable()` its working fine and the request is going to default /error page. but on adding `csrf().disable()` ,I am noticing a very unusual behaviour. once another endpoint ex. /test_url_3 is being called with an jwt header for authorization, next time onwards the endpoint(/test_url_2) is blocked even for unauthorized user, i.e. instead of going to the error page its calling the end point.
I am still new to spring security and spring, and not sure if I am writing some configuration wrong, please help me with the issue.

Comment: Please see the [JWT Login](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/tree/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login) sample. Note that you do not (and should not) provide a custom JWT filter.

Comment: please learn how to debug your spring application by enabling debug logs for spring security and read the docs and read the logs before asking on stack overflow.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't get exact meaning of the following sentences:

I am noticing a very unusual behaviour. once another endpoint ex. /test_url_3 is being called with an jwt header for authorization, next time onwards the endpoint(/test_url_2) is blocked even for unauthorized user, i.e. instead of going to the error page its calling the end point.

If you didn't get what exactly CSRF I recommend watching this video: https://youtu.be/uzZzlar-iQI from 1:08:00. If you want to authenticate url1 and don't want to authenticate url2 try the following code instead of using anyRequest().

```
 httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
           .authorizeRequests()
           .antMatchers('/ur1')
           .authenticated()
```

follow through this URL for more info on CSRF: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-csrf

Comment: So I want all the urls to be authenticated except the ones I mention in web.ignore. For authentication, I am using JWT token in the URL header. The expectation is all the unauthenticated endpoint call will be redirected to the default error page. But if I am adding `csrf().disable()` , even the unauthenticated(with no header) endpoint calls are getting executed.

Comment: This behaviour I am observing only after I have done an endpoint call with a JWT authentication token added to the header of it. Even if my next endpoint call does not have an auth token attached to its header, it's not going to the error page.

Comment: csrf().disable() will stop the creation of an extra token for each client using the application. Maybe the first request is storing some session Id. So once you have authenticated from the next time it's not looking for the session Id which is already present due to the first request. Hence try to check each URL is correctly authenticated or not in a new private window of browser.